# htaccess 301 redirect query to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

trying to redirect this query to a new domain:

```
www.domain.com/search.php?q=keyword
```

to

```
www.newdomain.com/search.php?q=keyword
```

keyword can be any word

And want to keep the rest in domain, I just need to redirect this query.
I try several ways and the one I found closer to solution is this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=1$
RewriteRule ^search\.php$ http://www.newdomain.com/search.php?q=$1 [R=301,L]
```

but does not work!
Hope someone could help me correcting this and also if this is the best way to do the job?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(search\.php)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: any advantage from using this new update instead the other answer?

Comment: Don't think other answer will work correctly as it has `?` in the end that will strip out original query string.

Comment: i was talking about your first code :)
you did add a new line

#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=.+ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(search\.php)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: Oh ok sorry for the confusion. New update just makes sure that rule is applied for `domain.com` or `www.domain.com`. Which may not be needed if you have `domain.com` hosted on a different host/vhost.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123$
RewriteRule ^/?product\.php$ http://website.com.au/product_123.php? [L,R=301]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?product\.php$ http://website.com.au/product_%1.php? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

this works and is simple

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [QSA]
```